# something like NOT LIKE (select statement from other table)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 3 tables

```
SUFFIX_LIST(Item VARCHAR),
PREFIX_LIST(Item VARCHAR), and
VALID_LIST(Part1 VARCHAR, Part2 VARCHAR)
```

now i need column VALID_LIST.Part1 & VALID_LIST.Part2 in way that 
Part1 doesnt match partially from any of the Item from SUFFIX_LIST and
Part2 doesnt match partially from any of the Item from PREFIX_LIST.

I am using, SQLite as my local database and using c# for application development!

Thanks in advance!

### edit for clarification

VALID LIST

```
sample1, somedomain.com
samplebanword, someotherdomain.com
simplestring, someotherotherdomain.net
morestring, my-domain.com
```

PREFIX_LIST

```
ban
text
```

SUFFIX_LIST

```
.net
otherother
```

now, what i want is, when the query i must get

```
Output
--------
sample1, somedomain.com
morestring, my-domain.com
```

Comment: Some examples might clarify your confusing question

Comment: I believe that your example is backwards from your description -- you're checking Part1 against PREFIX, not SUFFIX, and Part2 against SUFFIX, not PREFIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that works using the additional information you've supplied:

```
SELECT * FROM VALID_LIST WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM PREFIX_LIST WHERE VALID_LIST.Part1 LIKE '%' || Item || '%')
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM SUFFIX_LIST WHERE VALID_LIST.Part2 LIKE '%' || Item || '%')
```

You can see it in operation here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1da46/3/0

Comment: You're welcome.  I should point out that if the PREFIX and SUFFIX tables grow to any significant size, it may turn out to be a very *slow* charm.