# SQLite - Fastest way to read Data from SQLite Database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, query-optimization

i have a local SQLite database

TABLE DETAILS

```
-- Describe PREFIX_LIST
CREATE TABLE PREFIX_LIST(ITEM VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY)

-- Describe SUFFIX_LIST
CREATE TABLE SUFFIX_LIST(ITEM VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY)

-- Describe VALID_LIST
CREATE TABLE VALID_LIST (
    "PART1" TEXT,
    "PART2" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(PART1, PART2)
)
```

now this list is really huge, and i need need to save data from it.

Here is my implementation.

```
SQLiteConnection con = null;
SQLiteCommand cmd = null;
Connect(DbPath, ref con, ref cmd);

cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT PART1 || '@' || PART2 FROM VALID_LIST 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM PREFIX_LIST WHERE VALID_LIST.PART1 LIKE '%' || ITEM || '%') 
   AND NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM SUFFIX_LIST WHERE VALID_LIST.PART2 LIKE '%' || ITEM || '%')";

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    string savePath;

    if (SaveTextFile(out savePath) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(savePath);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            writer.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
        }
        writer.Close();
        writer.Dispose();
    }

}

reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
con.Close();
con.Dispose();

MessageBox.Show("List Saved!.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

I need some better way i can save list faster.
total entries in **VALID_LIST** is 2639117

and it took 15 minutes to save it for the above SQL QUERY!

please lmk if the sql query can be optimized!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Correlated subquery + `LIKE` = huge performance hit

Comment: @cdhowie - i know, but what are other solution? i think query must be optimized somehow!

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to optimize this without completely altering your schema.

Comment: @cdhowie - altering the schema is not a issue! i have just started the application and i expect all three list to get bigger!

Comment: Can you give some example data, and what results you want to get from the query?

Comment: Is the data in the PREFIX and SUFFIX tables internally formatted in any way?  Is ITEM expected to be a separate token (comma or string delimited or something) inside the PART1 or PART2 values?

Comment: Have you tried to fill flat lists of class objets using a straight query, then to process the data using LINQ ?

Comment: the data in the PREFIX & SUFFIX list are simple words.

Comment: basically i need all item from valid_list, where prefix_list.item is not a substring in valid_list.part1 and suffix_list.item is not a substring in valid_list.part2

Comment: If the ITEM is expected to be an entire word in PREFIX or SUFFIX, you may be able to use full text search: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html.

Comment: @Laurent - i am very sure that list is too huge to load it all in memory at a time, for this only reason i am doing all sorting & filtering via database!

Comment: What about this old trick using outer joins and NULL values ? http://databases.about.com/library/weekly/aa051203a.htm

Comment: @LarryLustig - the above link is not makin much sense into my HEAD, i am not much of sql guy!

Comment: @Laurent - on what column shall i make join? an example query?

Comment: Sorry, inner join is not applicable because you're using "LIKE". By the way, if there are PREFIX and SUFFIX, do you really need "%" wildcards on both sides of the string of the LIKE ?

Comment: @classic.programmer: Complete explanation of FTS added as an answer.

Comment: @cdhowie - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695393/something-like-not-like-select-statement-from-other-table/12695473

Comment: @Laurent - yes, that % is needed on both side!

Comment: @cdhowie - can this help ?

instead of reading it to data reader read all info into a temp table & then read that temp table direct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Queries with `LIKE` are going to be very slow in general unless the wildcard is attached to the suffix.  A predicate such as `LIKE '%foo'` cannot be indexed via typical string indexing.

You can however replace heavy `LIKE` usage in sqlite with its [full text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) (FTS) feature.

> The FTS3 and FTS4 extension modules allows users to create special
>   tables with a built-in full-text index (hereafter "FTS tables"). The
>   full-text index allows the user to efficiently query the database for
>   all rows that contain one or more words (hereafter "tokens"), even if
>   the table contains many large documents.

They have [an example](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1) that look promising in terms of performance on your use case.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);     /* FTS3 table */
CREATE TABLE enrondata2(content TEXT);                        /* Ordinary table *

SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata1 WHERE content MATCH 'linux';  /* 0.03 seconds */
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata2 WHERE content LIKE '%linux%'; /* 22.5 seconds */
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using full text search.

For this to work, the values in PREFIX and SUFFIX have to be tokenized (they must be separate words), and the ITEM you're trying to match must be a distinct token in one of the these values (not part of a word or two words together).  For instance, the strings in PREFIX and SUFFIX have to be something like 'RED BLUE GREEN' or 'DOG, CAT, CAPYBARA' and the values for ITEM must be RED, BLUE, GREEN, DOG, CAT, or CAPYBARA.

If those conditions are met you could enable full text search, recreate these tables as full text tables, and replace LIKE (and the wildcards) with MATCH.  In this case, SQLite will maintain on index on every *token* found in PREFIX or SUFFIX and that part of the searching will be much, much faster.

Unfortunately, enabling FTS in SQlite involves compiling the product from source code with one or more compile-time flags set.  I have no experience with this.

Comment: Is it true that your matching ITEM against individual words?  If so, put the words, one at a time, into their own rows.  You can make that work very quickly.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but what i am trying to do via sql is, make sure all my item in valid_list.part1 dont matches partially from all the items in prefix_list.item

Comment: No worries.  I'm suggesting that if the partial values are all separate words, you should split them into separate rows in the PREFIX and SUFFIX tables and then do a search with "=" instead of "LIKE".  This ONLY works if the values are distinct words and you're not looking "inside" words for matches.  Please post sample values from all tables.

Comment: nah sorry, none of the word are such, to be honest PART1 is email-user & PART2 is email-domain

Comment: so, together they make email! if abc@test.com is email, then abc = valid_list.part1 & test.com = valid_list.part2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want but it will help speed up the writing process.Try accumulating the strings you read from database in a string builder and then write to the file. 
For example you can read 100k string then write those 100k to the file at once.

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0; //to limit the number of rows stored in string builder.
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        builder.AppendLine(reader.GetString(0));
        count++;

        //store every 100k or so rows at once. 
        //This number depends on how much RAM 
        //you can allocate towards storing the string of rows.
        //If you have 2GB of free RAM
        //this number can easily be 1 million but it always depends on the
        //size of each string stored in database.
        if(count == 100000) 
        {
           File.AppendAllText(path, builder.ToString()); //Append all rows to the file
           builder.Clear(); //clear the string for next 100k rows of data
           count = 0; //Clear the counter value
        }
        count++
    }
```

Let me know if it helped.